# App Insights REST call using KQL query returns empty

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, azure-application-insights

Following Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/query/execute) I'd like to query an **App Insights** resource for trace events. If I directly access the trace using the specific endpoint:

```
https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/$aiAppId/events/traces
```

it perfectly works. But I'm unable to use a **KQL** query:

```
$aiAppId = 'my_app_insights_app_id'
$aiApiKey = 'my_app_insights_api_key'

$content = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/$aiAppId/query" `
    -Method Post -UseBasicParsing `
    -Headers @{
        'x-api-key' = $aiApiKey
     } `
    -Body @{
        'timespan' = 'PT60M'
        'query' = 'traces | where timestamp >= ago(30m)'
     }
).Content

$content | ConvertFrom-Json
```

It yields an empty result:

```
tables
------
{}
```

Executing the KQL query from **Azure portal** I get correct results.

Am I missing something?
Any help really appreciated.

Best regards.

Giacomo S. S.

Comment: To use POST, you need to
provide the header Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, and
specify the Analytics query in json, e.g. {"query": "analytics-query"}.

Comment: @NAS, thank you for your help. I see a different output but the same empty. https://imgur.com/a/naUAoFz.

Comment: you can check this for more info https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart

Comment: Can [this](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Query) help you? I found a get request: GET /v1/apps/{app-id}/query?query=requests | where timestamp > ago(30d) and client_City == "Redmond" | summarize clients = dcount(client_IP) by tod_UTC=bin(timestamp % 1d, 1h), resultCode | extend local_hour = (tod_UTC - 8h) % 24h

Comment: @Tiny-wa, the endpoint accept also a GET but I got always and empty result with a valid KQL query (that yields results in Azure portal).

Comment: @gsscoder if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks:).

Answer (score 1):

The type of `$content | ConvertFrom-Json` is `PSCustomObject`. So it shows the result as you mentioned:

[image]

You can use code like `$s = $content | ConvertFrom-Json`, then use `$s.tables.rows` or `$s.tables.columns` to display the details.

Or just use `$content`, then you can see the correct output:

[image]

And please consider writing your own logic to parse the result instead of directly use `ConvertFrom-Json`.

Comment: But Content property should contain the response body. And I see from your screenshot you're getting too an empty result.

Comment: @gsscoder the conten property has result. I print both the `$content` and `$s | ConvertTo-Json`, the `$content` has value, but the `$s | ConvertTo-Json` has no value. You can check the screenshot again.

Comment: @gsscoder I agree with ivan here. I tried his script and it worked for me.      $aiAppId = ''
$aiApiKey = ''

$content = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/$aiAppId/query" `
    -Method Post -UseBasicParsing `
    -Headers @{
        "content-type" = "application/json"
        'x-api-key' = $aiApiKey
     } `
    -Body '{
        "timespan" : "PT60M",
        "query" : "traces | where timestamp >= ago(90d)"
     }'
).Content

$content

Comment: @Tiny-wa I don't know... In any case the KQL query that returns on portal doesn't return on REST call.

Comment: @gsscoder, do you follow the instructions in the answer? we checked, the same records(from portal) are also returned by the rest call.

Comment: btw, my error was to not following scrupulously what explained in docs (https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference/post-query). I was finally able to get the KQL query executed: https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/3b1a5b39f528964b4cf9f03e6badced2. Thanks to all of you for the help!

Comment: @gsscoder, glad that it's solved. Actually I already mentioned that in the answer. If my answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks:).

Comment: @IvanYang I voted up cause it helped. But still not convinced that is correct converting the whole response to JSON.